# Database Exception Error SQLLITE and FLUTTER

Tags: mysql, json, flutter, sqlite

Can I get some help with this please...I am getting error like

```
1) near "VALUES": syntax error
I/flutter ( 6415): DatabaseException(near "VALUES": syntax error (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: INSERT INTO words (
```

here is my dart model code..it says something is wrong here

[Here][1]

Wordtable is my SQLite model where I'm saving the data and Word is my backend model where I'm fetching the data to save into SQLite one

I tried to make it short and precise as possible so please do let me know if any further clarification is needed.
Thank you and happy new year

```
class WordList {
  List<Word>? words;

  WordList({this.words});

  factory WordList.fromJson(List<dynamic> json, String lang) {
    List<Word> words = json.map((i) => Word.fromJson(i, lang)).toList();

    return new WordList(
      words: words,
    );
  }
}

class WordTableList {
  final List<WordTable>? words;

  WordTableList({this.words});

  factory WordTableList.fromJson(List<dynamic> json) {
    List<WordTable> words = json.map((e) => WordTable.fromMap(e)).toList();

    return new WordTableList(
      words: words,
    );
  }
}

////////////////////WordTable SQLLITE/////////////////////
class WordTable {
  static String table = 'words';
  int? WORD_ID;
  String? TINA;
  String? LETTER;
  String? NABA;
  String? ITAVI;
  String? LOMANIBAI;
  String? DEWA;
  String? IVAKAMACALA;
  String? COKE;
  String? IDUSIDUSI;
  // String? LINKED_SYN;
  String? IVOSAVOSA;
  String? ITAKATAKA;
  String? VOSA_VAKALATINA;
  String? WORDIMG;
  String? MAIN_AUDIO;
  String? STORY_AUDIO;

  WordTable.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    this.WORD_ID = json['word_id'];
    this.TINA = json['tina'];
    this.LETTER = json['letter'];
    this.NABA = json['naba'];
    this.ITAVI = json['itavi'];
    this.LOMANIBAI = json['lomanibai'];
    this.DEWA = json['dewa'];
    this.IVAKAMACALA = json['ivakamacala'];
    this.COKE = json['coke'];
    this.IDUSIDUSI = json['idusidusi'];
    //this.LINKED_SYN = json['ivosavosa'];
    this.IVOSAVOSA = json['ivosavosa'];
    this.ITAKATAKA = json['itakataka'];
    this.VOSA_VAKALATINA = json['vosa_vakalatina'];
    this.WORDIMG = json['word_main_image'];
    this.MAIN_AUDIO = json['word_main_audio'];
    this.STORY_AUDIO = json['story_audio'];
    // if (json['family'] != null) {
    //   this.plantFamily = PlantFamily.fromJson(json['family']);
    // }
  }

  WordTable.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    this.WORD_ID = json['word_id'] == null ? 0 : json['word_id'];
    this.TINA =
        json['tina'] == null ? "No Scientific Name Available" : json['tina'];
    this.LETTER =
        json['letter'] == null ? "No Local Name Available" : json['letter'];
    this.NABA = json['naba'] == null
        ? "storage/images/13293205681610263850.png"
        : json['naba'];
    this.ITAVI =
        json['itavi'] == null ? "No Description Available" : json['itavi'];
    this.LOMANIBAI = json['lomanibai'] == null
        ? "No Description Available"
        : json['lomanibai'];
    this.DEWA =
        json['dewa'] == null ? "No Distribution Available" : json['dewa'];
    this.IVAKAMACALA = json['ivakamacala'] == null
        ? "No Distribution Available"
        : json['ivakamacala'];
    this.COKE =
        json['coke'] == null ? "No Distribution Available" : json['coke'];
    this.IDUSIDUSI = json['idusidusi'] == null
        ? "No Description Available"
        : json['idusidusi'];
    this.IVOSAVOSA = json['ivosavosa'] == null
        ? "No Description Available"
        : json['ivosavosa'];
    this.ITAKATAKA = json['itakataka'] == null
        ? "No Description Available"
        : json['itakataka'];
    this.VOSA_VAKALATINA = json['vosa_vakalatina'] == null
        ? "No Description Available"
        : json['vosa_vakalatina'];
    this.WORDIMG = json['word_main_image'] == null
        ? "No Description Available"
        : json['word_main_image'];
    this.MAIN_AUDIO = json['word_main_audio'] == null
        ? "No Description Available"
        : json['word_main_audio'];
    this.STORY_AUDIO = json['story_audio'] == null
        ? "No Description Available"
        : json['story_audio'];
    // this.hpfMedicalUseOtherFj = json['hpf_medical_use_other_fj'] == null
    //     ? "No Description Available"
    //     : json['hpf_medical_use_other_fj'];
    // if (json['plant_family'] != null) {
    //   print('family is not null');
    //   this.plantFamily = new PlantFamily(
    //       bookChapterId: 0,
    //       hpfBotanicalCat: json['plant_botanical_category'],
    //       hpfBotanicalSubCat: json['plant_sub_botanical_category'],
    //       hpfFamilyName: json['plant_family'],
    //       id: 0);
    //}
  }

  static String plantTableQuery(WordTable words) {
    return ''' INSERT INTO words (
    word_id, 
    tina,
    letter,
    naba,
    itavi,
    lomanibai,
    dewa,
    ivakamacala,
    coke,
    idusidusi,
    ivosavosa,
    itakataka,
    vosa_vakalatina,
    word_main_image,
    word_main_audio,
    story_audio,
    VALUES (
    '${words.WORD_ID}',
    '${words.TINA}',
    '${words.LETTER}',
    '${words.NABA}',
    '${words.ITAVI}',
    '${words.LOMANIBAI}',
    '${words.DEWA}',
    '${words.IVAKAMACALA}',
    '${words.COKE}',
    '${words.IDUSIDUSI}',
    '${words.IVOSAVOSA}',
    '${words.ITAKATAKA}',
    '${words.VOSA_VAKALATINA}',
    '${words.WORDIMG}',
    '${words.MAIN_AUDIO}',
    '${words.STORY_AUDIO}'
    )''';
  }

  static const String CREATE_TABLE = '''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS words ( 
    word_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    tina TEXT,
    letter TEXT,
    naba TEXT,
    itavi TEXT,
    lomanibai TEXT,
    dewa TEXT,
    ivakamacala TEXT,
    coke TEXT,
    idusidusi TEXT,
    ivosavosa TEXT,
    itakataka TEXT,
    vosa_vakalatina TEXT,
    word_main_image TEXT,
    word_main_audio TEXT,
    story_audio TEXT,
)''';

  static const String DELETE_TABLE = 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS words';
}

//////////////////////////////WordTable SQLLITE END////////////////////////////////

class Word {
  static String table = 'words';
  int? WORD_ID;
  String? TINA;
  String? LETTER;
  String? NABA;
  String? ITAVI;
  String? LOMANIBAI;
  String? DEWA;
  String? IVAKAMACALA;
  String? COKE;
  String? IDUSIDUSI;
  String? LINKED_SYN;
  String? IVOSAVOSA;
  String? ITAKATAKA;
  String? VOSA_VAKALATINA;
  String? WORDIMG;
  String? MAIN_AUDIO;
  String? STORY_AUDIO;

  Word(
      {this.WORD_ID,
      this.TINA,
      this.LETTER,
      this.NABA,
      this.ITAVI,
      this.LOMANIBAI,
      this.DEWA,
      this.IVAKAMACALA,
      this.COKE,
      this.IDUSIDUSI,
      this.LINKED_SYN,
      this.IVOSAVOSA,
      this.ITAKATAKA,
      this.VOSA_VAKALATINA,
      this.WORDIMG,
      this.MAIN_AUDIO,
      this.STORY_AUDIO});

  factory Word.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json, String lang) {
    return Word(
        WORD_ID: json['word_id'] ?? "0",
        TINA: json['tina'] ?? "",
        LETTER: json['letter'] ?? "",
        NABA: json['naba'] ?? "0",
        ITAVI: json['itavi'] ?? "0",
        LOMANIBAI: json['lomanibai'] ?? "",
        DEWA: json['dewa'] ?? "",
        IVAKAMACALA: json['ivakamacala'] ?? "No Description Provided",
        COKE: json['coke'] ?? "",
        IDUSIDUSI: json['idusidusi'] ?? "",
        IVOSAVOSA: json['ivosavosa'] ?? "",
        ITAKATAKA: json['itakataka'] ?? "",
        VOSA_VAKALATINA: json['vosa_vakalatina'] ?? "",
        WORDIMG: json['word_main_image'] ?? "",
        MAIN_AUDIO: json['word_main_audio'] ?? "",
        STORY_AUDIO: json['story_audio'] ?? "");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query in `plantTableQuery` is incomplete:

> ````
>     INSERT INTO words (
>     ...
>     word_main_audio,
>     story_audio,
>     VALUES (
>     '${words.WORD_ID}',
>     '${words.TINA}',
>     ... ```
> ````

SQLite [has diagrams on their website](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html) that show the syntax of commands. They show you that in a `CREATE TABLE` query:

- the `column-name`s should be enclosed in brackets (you don't have a closing bracket `)`)
- there are commas between `column-name`s, but there can't be one before the closing bracket `)`.

The [`CREATE TABLE` diagram](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html) shows you that the query in variable `CREATE_TABLE` may not have a comma before the closing bracket `)` that encloses the `column-def`s, either:

> ```
>     ...
>     word_main_audio TEXT,
>     story_audio TEXT, 
> )
> ```

Comment: Thanks so much..since that query file doesnt show errors..it didnt spot where the closed bracket was missing lol..will keep in mind teh brackets and syntaxes closely next time

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error in your INSERT query near values.

Insert should be in this format

```
INSERT INTO table (column1,column2 ,..)
VALUES( value1, value2 ,...);
```

You are missing closing brackets just after column story_audio.

```
static String plantTableQuery(WordTable words) {
    return ''' INSERT INTO words (
    word_id, 
    tina,
    letter,
    naba,
    itavi,
    lomanibai,
    dewa,
    ivakamacala,
    coke,
    idusidusi,
    ivosavosa,
    itakataka,
    vosa_vakalatina,
    word_main_image,
    word_main_audio,
    story_audio) 
    VALUES(
    '${words.WORD_ID}',
    '${words.TINA}',
    '${words.LETTER}',
    '${words.NABA}',
    '${words.ITAVI}',
    '${words.LOMANIBAI}',
    '${words.DEWA}',
    '${words.IVAKAMACALA}',
    '${words.COKE}',
    '${words.IDUSIDUSI}',
    '${words.IVOSAVOSA}',
    '${words.ITAKATAKA}',
    '${words.VOSA_VAKALATINA}',
    '${words.WORDIMG}',
    '${words.MAIN_AUDIO}',
    '${words.STORY_AUDIO}'
    )''';
  }
```

Comment: Thanks so much..since that query file doesnt show errors..it didnt spot where the closed bracket was missing lol..will keep in mind teh brackets and syntaxes closely next time